# Volley doesn't fetch response if it takes too long

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to fetch the response from my website but is takes my website about 3 to 5 seconds to respond because the website does a lot of computation with the input.

I'm trying to use volley for android to fetch the response but it gives no response nor any errors. When I change my website code so that it just returns text without computation(less than a second to response) volley gives me the response.

So I'm very sure that the problem is because the response takes a lot of time.

Here is my code:

```
public class ADMRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String GET_ADM_LINK = "http://www.example.com";


    private Map<String, String> params;

    public ADMRequest(String s1, Response.Listener<String> listener) {

        super(Method.POST, GET_ADM_LINK, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("rs",s1);

    }


    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {

        return params;

    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.e("Response", "1");
        Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {


                Log.e("Response", "2");
                Log.e("Response", response);
                Log.e("Response", "3");



                finish();

            }
        };

        Log.e("Response", "4");
        ADMRequest admrequest = new ADMRequest("text", responselis);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        queue.add(admrequest);
        Log.e("Response", "5");

    }
}
```

When the website takes too long (1 4 5) is logged, on fast response (1 4 5 2 responseHere 3) is logged.

Answer (score 1):

By default, a Volley Request [uses a `DefaultRetryPolicy`](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/95f64de9bfa2ee44d6cf93a6dc4b980e5ec56f6a/src/main/java/com/android/volley/Request.java#L153), which defaults to a default timeout [`DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS` set to 2.5 seconds](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/ddfb86659df59e7293df9277da216d73c34aa800/src/main/java/com/android/volley/DefaultRetryPolicy.java#L36).

Just set a new RetryPolicy on your request as part of the class declaration:

```
public class ADMRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String GET_ADM_LINK = "http://www.example.com";

    private Map<String, String> params;

    public ADMRequest(String s1, Response.Listener<String> listener) {

        super(Method.POST, GET_ADM_LINK, listener, null);

        setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("rs",s1);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 0, 100000f));

here you can override retry policy of volley. Like : first parameter is initial TimeOut In MilliSeconds.So if you increase it , the time out of a network call will increase.

Hope, it helps.